# Enable file logging on IIS for serilog

Tags: iis, .net-core, serilog

I want to enable file logging on IIS to resolve an issue locally on IIS. Following is the code I am using. It works when I run on visual studio and logs to a file but not when I deployed to IIS. Folder has enough permission to create a file and also I created the folder and file. What am I missing here ?

**Program.cs**

```
        var path = @"C:\workspace\Logs\Log-{Date}.txt";

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console(
                outputTemplate:
                "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level}] {SourceContext}{NewLine}{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}{NewLine}",
                theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Literate)
            .WriteTo.File(path, fileSizeLimitBytes: 1_000_000,
                rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
                shared: true,
                flushToDiskInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            .CreateLogger();
```

**enable useSerialLog()**

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddAutofac())
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseSerilog()
                .Build();
```

Comment: I can't spot any problems with the code - some kind of permissions issue would still be my best guess. Enabling `SelfLog` and sending its output somewhere else (a temporary text file?) may help uncover the cause: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics

Answer (score 12):

Serilog works perfectly on local. For IIS the log file folder need IIS User Permission.

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
               .MinimumLevel
               .Information()
               .WriteTo.RollingFile(@"C:\inetpub\serilog\agilogoservicelogs\{Date}.txt", LogEventLevel.Information)
               .WriteTo.Seq("http://localhost:5341")
               .CreateLogger();

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }
```

Update your controller :

```
public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ScrumUserController> _logger;

        public ValuesController(ILogger<ScrumUserController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Agilibo Service start running");
            return new string[] { "Agilibo Core", "Service" };
        }
    }
```

Now give folder permission on deployed IIS.

[image]

Comment: Setting the permissions to **Full control** for **IIS_IUSRS** and **DefaultAppPool** like suggested from the Serilog discussion here (https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/921) didn't help me either... Fun fact: The IIS **STDOUT** logging shows that the Serilog logging works theoretically...

Comment: Okay, my error was way more stupid... **If debug** cause the issue... :D

Comment: Hi I'm trying to create the file log inside the directory of my application published but the file never is created. When I start the application in Visual Studio all works but when I consume the application published the file is not created in that folder

Comment: @kintela please add folder permission for IIS_IUSRS, where the file will be write.

Answer (score 9):

If you use .net core ,because default application pool identity:
**ApplicationPoolIdentity** has no write permission.

You should:

Change application pool user to Local System...

Or-

Give **ApplicationPoolIdentity** write permission:

ApplicationPoolIdentity is a virtual name , you can use "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" set the permission.

[image]

you can use cli do the same work

```
ICACLS C:\sites\MyWebApp /grant "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool":F
```

Don't forget **restart applicationpool and site**.

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#application-pools)

Comment: Thx you @menxin for pointing out this possibility (this was helpfull using .NET6 app deployed on IIS).
In addition, as explains in the doc, when the pool used by the application is not DefaultAppPool use
"IIS AppPool\{_APP POOL NAME_}"
where the placeholder {_APP POOL NAME_} is the app pool name

Comment: "Changing application pool user to Local System" is helped me!